# Android ListView Italic

Tags: android, android-layout, italic

I was wondering if it's possible to get the following output when using `ListActivity`:

Name - *Age*

Name - *Age*

etc.

So name normal and age italic.

I'm currently using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" >
</TextView>
```

And java:

```
FeedParser parser = new AndroidSaxFeedParser("http://www.example.com/test.xml");
messages = parser.parse();
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
for (Message msg : messages){
     titles.add(msg.name+"\nAge: "+msg.age+"");
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, titles);
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use two `TextView` widgets (one for age set to italic), or use a `SpannedString` with inline markup for the italics. One way to get the `SpannedString` is to use `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: @Kevin: Change all `<String>` to `<CharSequence>` (e.g., `List<CharSequence>`).

Comment: Ah, thank you. Funny that Html.fromHtml() translates "<em>test</em>" to bold

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set [HTML formatted text](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling).

Have your string look like this `Bob - <i>30</i>`.